# The azurerm_virtual_machine is not displaying in the Terraform plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using an existing template from github and have modified it a little bit. When I terraform.exe plan it says it will deploy 4 resources (NIC, NSG, VM-SA, and Resource Group).

I am trying to deploy a VM and have it joined to an existing VNet.

I have removed the NIC to see if it would add the windows VM for deployment and it does not

main.tf

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "************************************"
    tenant_id       = "************************************"
    client_id       = "************************************"
    client_secret   = "************************************"
}

module "os" {
  source       = "./os"
  vm_os_simple = "${var.vm_os_simple}"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "vm" {
  name     = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  location = "${var.location}"
  tags     = "${var.tags}"
}

resource "random_id" "vm-sa" {
  keepers = {
    vm_hostname = "${var.vm_hostname}"
  }

  byte_length = 6
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "${var.network_security_group}"
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "vm-sa" {
  count                    = "${var.boot_diagnostics == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
  name                     = "bootdiag${lower(random_id.vm-sa.hex)}"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.vm.name}"
  location                 = "${var.location}"
  account_tier             = "${element(split("_", var.boot_diagnostics_sa_type),0)}"
  account_replication_type = "${element(split("_", var.boot_diagnostics_sa_type),1)}"
  tags                     = "${var.tags}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm-windows" {
  count                         = "${((var.is_windows_image == "true" || contains(list("${var.vm_os_simple}","${var.vm_os_offer}"), "Windows")) && var.data_disk == "false") ? var.nb_instances : 0}"
  name                          = "${var.vm_hostname}${count.index}"
  location                      = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name           = "${azurerm_resource_group.vm.name}"
  vm_size                       = "${var.vm_size}"
  network_interface_ids         = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.vm.*.id, count.index)}"]
  delete_os_disk_on_termination = "${var.delete_os_disk_on_termination}"

  storage_image_reference {
    id        = "${var.vm_os_id}"
    publisher = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_publisher, module.os.calculated_value_os_publisher) : ""}"
    offer     = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_offer, module.os.calculated_value_os_offer) : ""}"
    sku       = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? coalesce(var.vm_os_sku, module.os.calculated_value_os_sku) : ""}"
    version   = "${var.vm_os_id == "" ? var.vm_os_version : ""}"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "osdisk-${var.vm_hostname}-${count.index}"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    managed_disk_type = "${var.storage_account_type}"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.vm_hostname}${count.index}"
    admin_username = "${var.admin_username}"
    admin_password = "${var.admin_password}"
  }

  tags = "${var.tags}"

  os_profile_windows_config {
    provision_vm_agent = true
  }

  boot_diagnostics {
    enabled     = "${var.boot_diagnostics}"
    storage_uri = "${var.boot_diagnostics == "true" ? join(",", azurerm_storage_account.vm-sa.*.primary_blob_endpoint) : "" }"
  }
}

#refer to a subnet
data "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
  name                 = "SubnetName"
  virtual_network_name = "VNetName"
  resource_group_name  = "VNetresourceGroupName"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm" {
  count                         = "${var.nb_instances}"
  name                          = "nic-${var.vm_hostname}-${count.index}"
  location                      = "${azurerm_resource_group.vm.location}"
  resource_group_name           = "${azurerm_resource_group.vm.name}"
  network_security_group_id     = "${azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig${count.index}"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.test.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }

  tags = "${var.tags}"
}
```

Expected results should be Deploy a VM, Storage Account, Network Security Group and Nic that is joined to an existing VNet

Comment: What is the error do you get?

Comment: I do not receive any errors. Terraform console shows 4 resources to deploy in which none are the VM.

Comment: So what do you want while the code works to you?

Comment: I did not include the vars file in this but the code should deploy a Windows VM joined to an existing VNET and also deploy NSG, Storage account

Comment: Do you want to know how to define the variable indeed? Or you just want to know how to create a windows VM through the Terraform? Please provide more information to describe what you want.

Comment: How to create a windows VM joined to an existing VNET through Terraform.

Comment: Made some changes it that did help. Not sure what was going on with the other one. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an Azure VM through Terraform, you can see the whole steps in [Create a complete Linux virtual machine infrastructure in Azure with Terraform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/terraform-create-complete-vm), it's a Linux VM, but you can change the image into windows and the `os_profile_linux_config` into `os_profile_windows_config`.

In an existing Vnet, you can use the Terraform data to quote the Vnet as you provide:

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "existing" {
  name                 = "SubnetName"
  virtual_network_name = "VNetName"
  resource_group_name  = "VNetresourceGroupName"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myterraformnic" {
    name                      = "myNIC"
    location                  = "eastus"
    resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.myterraformnsg.id}"

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "myNicConfiguration"
        subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.existing.id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.id}"
    }

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}
```

The whole Terraform code here and you can change the information about the VM as you want.

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    client_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    client_secret   = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    tenant_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

# Create a resource group if it doesn’t exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myterraformgroup" {
    name     = "myResourceGroup"
    location = "eastus"

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# the existing subnet of the virtual network 
data "azurerm_subnet" "existing" {
  name                 = "SubnetName"
  virtual_network_name = "VNetName"
  resource_group_name  = "VNetresourceGroupName"
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "myterraformpublicip" {
    name                         = "myPublicIP"
    location                     = "eastus"
    resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    allocation_method            = "Dynamic"

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create Network Security Group and rule
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "myterraformnsg" {
    name                = "myNetworkSecurityGroup"
    location            = "eastus"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"

    security_rule {
        name                       = "RDP"
        priority                   = 1001
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "3306"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myterraformnic" {
    name                      = "myNIC"
    location                  = "eastus"
    resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.myterraformnsg.id}"

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "myNicConfiguration"
        subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.existing.id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.id}"
    }

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Generate random text for a unique storage account name
resource "random_id" "randomId" {
    keepers = {
        # Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
        resource_group = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    }

    byte_length = 8
}

# Create storage account for boot diagnostics
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mystorageaccount" {
    name                        = "diag${random_id.randomId.hex}"
    resource_group_name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    location                    = "eastus"
    account_tier                = "Standard"
    account_replication_type    = "LRS"

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "myterraformvm" {
    name                  = "myVM"
    location              = "eastus"
    resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id}"]
    vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

    storage_os_disk {
        name              = "myOsDisk"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        create_option     = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
    }

    storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter-Server-Core-smalldisk"
    version   = "latest"
  }

    os_profile {
        computer_name  = "myvm"
        admin_username = "azureuser"
        admin_password = "Passwd@!1234"
    }

    os_profile_windows_config {
        provision_vm_agent = true
    }

    boot_diagnostics {
        enabled = "true"
        storage_uri = "${azurerm_storage_account.mystorageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint}"
    }

    tags {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}
```

For more details, see [Azure Virtual Machine in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html).